# Using SmartThreadPool MaxThreads=5 and still seeing more

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadpool

I started using SmartThreadPool after i read it is recommended as a replacement
of thread in cases you want your threads to have their own pool.

I set the max threads number to 5 but still see in task manager that it uses 10-12 threads.

Is this problem familiar for some of you?

Comment: read this thread, it does not answer your question straight, but it explains a lot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043909/threadpool-setmaxthreads-and-setminthreads-magic-number

Comment: It explains a lot about thread pool.
But SmartThreadPool suppose to be "smarter" and non static so it can be like a private pool for vip threads.
As i see now it is not enough.

Comment: That class doesn't do anything to limit the number of threads that the CLR itself uses.

Comment: I create new SmartThreadPool in my windows service and set MaxThreads=5. So i expect that my smart thread pool that i initialized will use max 5 threads. 
I do not care what other process do with my other system threads.

Comment: Great reading,might help you...http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7933/Smart-Thread-Pool

Comment: Why don't you use the Threads window in the visual studio debugger to see what the other threads are doing?  Like others suggested, It's possible that the extra threads have nothing to do with your smart thread pool at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The threads used by the `SmartThreadPool` and the threads used by the whole application are different things. The thread pool is a collection of threads used to to some work, but a .net app will have multiple background threads (e.g. garbage collector) running at the same time, which is what you're seeing in the task manager.

Comment: I checked the number and you are correct.
The service using other thread for its own use.

Thanks.